# Protractor test for Angular: how to get exact match for column name

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have just started writing protractor tests, so I am a beginner with this.

I have the following angular code I am trying to test:

```
<tr ng-repeat="identifier in contentIdentifiers">
    <td>{{identifier.contentIdentifier}}</td>
    <td>{{identifier.contentIdentifierTypeDescription}}</td>
    <td>{{identifier.licensedWebsiteIdentifier}}</td>
</tr>
```

where content identifier has the following values:

```
contentIdentifiers = [
    {
        contentIdentifier: '123-123-1-ABC',
        contentIdentifierTypeDescription: 'DOI',
        licensedWebsiteIdentifier: 'TEST WEBSITE'
    },
    {
        contentIdentifier: 'ABC-DEF',
        contentIdentifierTypeDescription: 'ISBN',
        licensedWebsiteIdentifier: 'TEST WEBSITE'
    },
];
```

And this is my relevant protractor snippet:

```
var identifier = element.all(by.repeater("identifier in contentIdentifiers").column("identifier.contentIdentifier"));
expect(identifier.get(0).getText()).toEqual("123-123-1-ABC");
expect(identifier.get(1).getText()).toEqual("ABC-DEF");
```

For which I get the error:
 Expected 'DOI' to equal 'ABC-DEF'.

If I change it to:

```
expect(identifier.get(2).getText()).toEqual("ABC-DEF");
```

then it passes.

From this I think the issue is that column("identifier.contentIdentifier") also matches 'contentIdentifierTypeDescription'.

This data comes from the server, and I cannot change this for the sake of the test. Hence I would like a solution to get the list of the desired column only. Any options to get an exact column name match?

Comment: why do you have by.repeater("identifier in agreement.contentIdentifiers") and not by.repeater("identifier in contentIdentifiers")?

Comment: sorry i modified the question to simplify and forgot to modify it there, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following works:

```
var identifier = element.all(by.repeater("identifier in contentIdentifiers"))
                        .all(by.exactBinding("identifier.contentIdentifier"))
expect(identifier.get(0).getText()).toEqual("123-123-1-ABC");
expect(identifier.get(1).getText()).toEqual("ABC-DEF");
```

Its not .column syntax but, it seems to behave the same way, and give the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using the [by.exactRepeater](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater) finder. It sounds a bit weird that it modifies the subsequent `column` method behaviour but [it does](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.1.0/lib/locators.js#L274).